Are there theorem dual to Tarjan's theorem for breath first search?
In "Depth-First Search and Linear Graph Algorithms" Tarjan proposed following theorem as the foundation of depth-first search (rephrase a little bit):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected (undirected) graph and $v\in V$ be a vertex, then there is a directed tree as subgraph of $G$ such that:

$v$ is the root of $G$.
Any edge $(p,q) \in E$ is non-crossing, namely $p$ is an ancestor of $q$, or $q$ is an ancestor of $p$


And there is a "one-word proof": DFS (depth-first search). Moreover, Tarjan proved that all such trees are generated by DFS. My question is, are there theorem that could characterize all trees generated by breadth-first search?

BFS trees are a standard notion like DFS trees. See for example Chapter 22 of Introduction to Algorithms, by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein (aka. CLRS). Notably the following exercise (emphasis mine):

A depth-first forest classifies the edges of a graph into tree, back, forward, and cross edges. A breadth-first tree can also be used to classify the edges reachable from the source of the search into the same four categories.
a. Prove that in a breadth-first search of an undirected graph, the following properties hold:

There are no back edges and no forward edges.
For each tree edge $(u,v)$, we have $v.d=u.d+1$.
For each cross edge $(u,v)$, we have $v.d=u.d$ or $v.d=u.d+1$.

b. Prove that in a breadth-first search of a directed graph, the following properties hold:

There are no forward edges.
For each tree edge $(u,v)$, we have $v.d=u.d+1$.
For each cross edge $(u,v)$, we have $v.d≤u.d+1$.
For each back edge $(u,v)$, we have $0≤v.d≤u.d$.



I guess it's not a sufficient condition. Anyway I think that's a correct direction to understand BFS trees.

This is an attempt; please check.
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected (undirected) graph and $v\in V$ be a vertex, then consider all subgraphs $T=(V,F)$ of $G$ such that:

For each vertex $w\in V$, its distance to $v$ is the same in $G$ and $T$.

There is a total order $<$ on $V$ such that:
a. For each vertex $w \in V: v \leq w$.
b. An edge $\{ w,x \} \in E$ is in $F$ if and only if there is no edge $\{ y,x \} \in E$ with $y < w$.


The trees produced by BFS should be exactly the trees satisfying this condition; the order is a BFS order. A proof should be analogous to a proof of Tarjan's theorem.

Here's a possible counterexample in my mind: consider graph with edges $(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5)$. With root $1$ the tree $(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)$ is not a BFS tree ($4,5$ should have same ancestors).

Thank you. Yes, I do think all BFS visits all children of a node in sequence, without visiting any other nodes in between. So I need to fix this answer.

I have added a condition, but I should really do the proof first. I hope someone comes up with a better answer.
